# How to apply a ggtheme in function and apply labels on graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I am looking to apply a theme from `ggthemes` library to a `ggplot` inside of a function. However, it would seem that the `ggthemes` prevents the labels from showing. Why is this behavior happening?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)

d <- sample_n(diamonds, size = 50)
p <- ggplot(d, aes(carat, price)) + geom_point()

f1 <- function(g, title) {
  g %+% theme_few() %+% ggtitle(title)
}

f2 <- function(g, title) {
  g %+% ggtitle(title)
}

f1(p, "testing")
f2(p, "testing")
```

`f1` prevents the title from showing.

`f2` seems to display the title.

I ultimately would like to apply the theme inside of the function.

Thank you.

Comment: I might just realized that this is the `theme_few` maybe. Perhaps, the recent update of the `ggthemes` package changed this theme? My current version of `ggthemes` is 3.5.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `plot.title` is removed when using `theme_few()`.  You can just add it back in the same function:

```
f3 <- function(g, title) {
  g %+% ggtitle(title) %+% theme_few() %+%
    theme(plot.title = element_text(color="black"))
}
```

Now the following should work:

```
f3(p, "testing")
```

## Cause of issue:

Actually it looks like `plot.title` isn't removed and that the real problem is affecting much more than just the title.  It looks like `ggthemes` inherits all colors from the package data `ggthemes_data`.  However, they recently renamed the colors for `ggthemes_data$few` (from `black` to `Black`) but failed to update the functions, which is causing all color elements in the `theme_few()` to be read as `NA` now, thus eliminating the element from the theme.

So in the case for title, the `theme_few` is calling for `ggthemes_data$few$dark["black"]` when it should call for `ggthemes_data$few$dark["Black"]`.  It looks like this issue will affect all color elements in this particular function, so I would not use this version of `ggthemes` for the time being. I'm surprised this oversight didn't get caught!

Comment: This is makes sense! Thank you!

Comment: I was going to open a github issue, but looks like this exact issue was already opened: https://github.com/jrnold/ggthemes/issues/91
You can roll-back to version 3.4.2 or install the github version which should fix it